# While loop breaks but the code after it is never executed

Tags: c++, sockets, while-loop

Here is the method where the while loop resides. I am just connecting to a server , sending an HTTP Request and reading the response. When I debug, I still cannot see why this while loop is not passed.

```
void HttpSocket::Get(string address)
{
    std::string response, host, httpRequest;
    uint32_t ipAddress;
    ParseRequest(address, host, httpRequest);
    ResolveHostAddress(host, ipAddress);
    HttpSocket::Connect(ipAddress);
    strcpy(bufferToSend, httpRequest.c_str());
    n = write(sockfd,bufferToSend,strlen(bufferToSend));

    if (n < 0) { throw IO_Exception("Cannot send request.");     }
    memset(bufferToSend, 0, 500);

    memset(bufferToReceive, 0, 200);
    n = read(sockfd,bufferToReceive,200);

    if (n <= 0){
        throw IO_Exception("Cannot read response.");
    }
    else
    {
        response += bufferToReceive;

        while(n != 0)
        {
            n = 0;
            memset(bufferToReceive, 0, 200);
            n = read(sockfd,bufferToReceive,200);
            response += bufferToReceive;
            cout << "still in the loop" << n << endl;
        }
        cout << "Response: " << response << endl;
    }
}
```

By the way `n` is `volatile int` thus, I don't think compiler optimization causes it. FYI, Everything is fine and working until the last while loop.

Comment: Stack trace / error?

Comment: @Jeff no error. Btw I am working on Qt. Moreover "still in the loop" is not printed forever. Thus I can see  program goes out of while but then passes the next line of code

Comment: Think about this: You have a buffer of 200 characters (I assume, you don't show the actual declaration), and you read into (and potentially fill) all of this buffer. Where then is the string terminator? What do you think happens when you treat this buffer (without terminator) as a string?

Comment: Since `n` is volatile, is there any other process that might be concurrently modifying it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg when we concatenate a char* to string I believe it is not necessary to null terminate manually. Am I wrong?

Comment: To clarify - do you see "Response:" message? And, regardless, any particular reason for making n a global variable?

Comment: @SashaPachev Yes I can see. When I print response in the while loop, I see the response.

Comment: Yes you are wrong, `std::string` will treat a `char*` as a C-style string which needs a terminator. How else would the code know how long the string is? Since you potentially have none you have *undefined behavior* which could explain your problems.

Comment: Or, you know, it could be that you're trying to read from a blocking socket? Unfortunately the UB you might have means that all bets are off.

Comment: You copy the string you're sending into a dumber buffer, forcing you to compute the length of the string twice (once to copy it and then again when you call `strlen` on it) even though you already know it, since the string has a length function. Why would you even think of doing something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::read()` is a synchronous function. When there is nothing left on your socket to be read, the call to `n = read(sockfd,bufferToReceive,200);` just <s>hangs</s> blocks waiting new information.

To solve your problem, you should set the socket as [non-blocking](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) and read it with [`::recv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) which would return [`-E_WOULDBLOCK`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) if there is no data available:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
flags = ::fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
flags |= O_NONBLOCK;
::fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
```

An alternative would be to check for available data before `read`ing the file descriptor:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
int count;
::ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &count);
```

Comment: The behavior is rather called _blocking_ not _"hanging"_, but anyways your answer is correct.

Comment: you should have edited my answer, I definitely would have accepted it ;)

Comment: Solved. Thank you. The problem was simpler than I thought, yet very fundamental not to be seen.

Comment: The behavior you say (returning `-EWOULDBLOCK`) is what the kernel does, but user-space interface would have `read` return `-1` and set `errno` to `EWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: @YSC Oh, you did your edit very well. I would have, but from my tablet it's much harder. A bit of pushing you, seems to be taking the right action straight away ;-) ...

Comment: While this does correctly explain the problem, switching to non-blocking I/O is usually not the right fix. Usually the fix is to not call `read` if you have no reason to think the other side is going to send anything or to do everything you currently need to do before you call `read` so waiting for more data is no problem.